# action script 3 whole number as a division output

Tags: actionscript-3

**hello, I want to get whole number after division.**

```
x = 3/2;   //results x = 1 and not 1.5
```

**how to do this in as3??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just cast the result of the division to an integer:

`var x : int = int(3/2);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math.floor` to get the whole number:

```
var x:Number = Math.floor(3/2);
```

`Math.floor()` rounds down to the next integer number. So 1.9 becomes 1.

`Math.ceil()` rounds up to the next integer. So 1.1 would become 2.

`Math.round()` rounds to the closest integer value. So 1.5 would become 2.

Comment: yeah thank you very much!! I appreciate your help. but this was not exactly what i needed... i need it to round of to lower whole number... though i could have used your first method by subtracting 1 from result.... :) thank you very much!!

Comment: Math.floor() does round to the lower whole number. That is exactly what that function does. Math.floor(3/2) returns 1, exactly as you requested.